# Looking for a fast reduction algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, numba

I am looking for data structures and an algorithm for a Python/numpy/numba/C-extension implementation to improve the performance over my current approach to solve the following reduction problem:

## Input

I have a very large structured (Numpy) array of records in the format ``

```py
iarr = numpy.array(
    [([entityId, subentityId], subentityValue),
     ...,
     ...
    ], dtype=[('e', '<2u4'), ('r', '<f4')])
```

- There are `m` entities (order of millions) and `n` subentities (<20).
- There are no duplicate entity/subentity combinations.
- It is not known beforehad what `m` or `n` is.
- The number of subentities varies from entity to entity but is pre-dominantly 8 or 6 per entity.
- The array is unordered.

## Expected Output

I need to find the maximum or minimum `subentityValue` per `entityId`.

I don't need to retain the information from which `subentityId` the value came from.

The result should be an array of records like this:

```py
oarr = numpy.array(
    [(entityId, subentityValue),
     ...,
     ...
    ], dtype=[('e', '<u4'), ('r', '<f4')])
```

- The result array does not need to be ordered.
- The array is created either for max-values or for min-values, hence `entityId`s in the array are unique.

Equally well, the output could be a dictionary with `entityId`s as keys and max or min `subentityValues` as values.

## Current Implementation (slow!)

My initial approach using Python, Numpy and Numba was (described here for finding the maximum `subentityValue` per `entitId`):

1. Initialise a dictionary (`numba.typed.Dict`) with keys being unique `entityId`s and an initial value that is garanteed to be smaller than any `subentityValue` found in the array (for example -99999.9).

   ```py
   odict = numba.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=nb.int64, value_type=nb.float64)  # types for compatability to Python's dict

   smallest_r = nb.float64(-99999.9)

   for entity_id in np.unique(iarr['e'].astype(np.int64)):
            odict[entity_id] = smallest_r
   ```
2. Loop through the records in the input array and compare the value of `dictionary[entityId]` with the record's `entityValue` and

   a) if `dictionary[entityId]` is larger than `entityValue` don't do anything,

   b) if `dictionary[entityId]` is smaller than `entityValue` overwrite it with the `entityValue`.

   ```
   for i in numba.prange(iarr['e'].shape[0]):
       if odict[iarr['e'][i]] < iarr['r'][i]:
           odict[iarr['e'][i]] = iarr['r'][i]
   ```
3. Return the dictionary `odict` as a result.

This works fine but is by far the biggest bottleneck in the system.

To improve performance I attempted to parallize this (`@numba.jit(..., parallel=True)`), only to find out that `numba`'s `typed.Dict` is not thread-safe and giving me incorrect results in that case.

---

I am perfectly happy to ditch my solution completely in favour of something better (faster).
Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: @itprorh66, why are you recommending this for CR, when there are dozens of 'make my loops faster' questions every week?

Comment: Is the `subentityId` also unordered or only the `entityId`? Anyway, your data structure looks like a sparse matrix, where you want to find min (ignoring zeros) or max values. On every performance related question it would be good to have an input of realistic size and a comparison how your current algorithm performs on such a task.

Comment: @max9111, yes, `subentityId`s are also unordered. My test input array condists of 10_000_000 unique entities with 8 unique subentities each.

Comment: @max9111, I am not sure what you mean by "comparison how it performs". Comparison against what? Running my solution against that test array takes 33 seconds (excluding numba's compile time) on my machine. But that is very much machine dependent, no?

Answer (score 0):

To group source rows (by the first element of *e*) and then compute
both *min* and *max*, for each group, it is more covenient to use
*Pandas* instead of *Numpy*.

Start from necessary imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

For the test purpose, I created the source array as:

```
iarr = np.array([
    ([10, 1], 10.5), ([10, 1], 9.5), ([10, 1], 10.0),
    ([10, 2], 9.1),  ([10, 2], 9.2), ([10, 2], 9.4),
    ([10, 3], 7.5),  ([10, 3], 9.7), ([10, 3], 8.0),
    ([20, 2], 7.3),  ([20, 2], 7.1), ([20, 2], 8.0),
    ([20, 3], 7.3),  ([20, 3], 9.7), ([20, 3], 8.0)],
    dtype=[('e', '<u4', (2,)), ('r', '<f4')])
```

The first step is to create a pandasonic *Series* with:

- values from *r* column,
- the index (actually a **MultiIndex**) created from *e* column.

The code to do it is:

```
s = pd.Series(iarr['r'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(iarr['e'].T))
```

Then, to get the result, with both *min* and *max*, as a DataFrame, run:

```
result = s.groupby(level=0).agg(['min', 'max'])
```

The index (the leftmost, unnamed column) holds *entityId* and "actual"
columns contain both *min* and *max*.

The result is:

```
    min   max
10  7.5  10.5
20  7.1   9.7
```

If you need, you can convert it to a *Numpy* array:

```
oarr = np.core.records.fromarrays(
    result.reset_index().values.T,
    names='entityId, min, max', formats='u4, f4, f4')
```

My code should operate substantially faster than plain pythonic
solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I learned something new! For an array of 10_000_000 entities with 8 subentities each, your solution is in the same ballpark as my (sequential numba) solution. 33 seconds for pandas vs 39 seconds for numba.